# Make Django build-in send_mail function working with html by default

Tags: django, django-email

I want to substitute build-in **send_mail** function, that works only with plain-text emails, with my own smart **send_mail** function, that generates both html and plain-text versions automatically. Everything works as expected for my own emails, defined in my own application. I can do it in views.py in this fashion:

```
from django.core import mail
from utils import send_mail as send_html_mail
mail.send_mail = send_html_mail
```

But the problem still appears with emails of third-side applications. There all imports already completed before my code with monkey-patching of **send_mail** function.

Is it possible to override this function before all imports of all django applications? Or may be there is another solution of this issue. I really don't want to patch code with sending emails of these third-party applications. It's much easy just to put html-template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote application for quickly switching from plain-text emails to html based emails for all project's applications. It will work without modifying any Django code or code of other third-part applications.

Check it out here: https://github.com/ramusus/django-email-html

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.2 allows for pluggable email backends: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-e-mail-backend

Comment: My problem is deeper. I already use custom backend from mailer application. This app at first put email to Db, and after send it by cron job. It's not possible to write wrapper around **mailer email backend* for some reasons. Because this applications use several ways to put email to DB.

Comment: If you are referencing `django-mailer` it does have its own backend that puts messages in the DB. However there is a setting to change the backend which sends the mail as well: `MAILER_EMAIL_BACKEND`

Comment: Yeah, it's clear for me, thanks. It must works, but I see one bad side of this way. We will generate, put into DB, get from DB incorrectly created email message, and only at last moment, make it correct (with html and plain-text bodies). That's not good at all. For example if I need to cover this system by tests, I will need to switch email backend to local-memory-backend and work with badly generated email messages.

Comment: I realized my idea. If you are interested, check out this application github.com/ramusus/django-email-html

Answer (score 2):

From Django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

No send_mail() required.

Comment: The problem connected with emails inside third-party applications, that I don't wont to rewrite. They use build-in send_mail function, but I want to switch all emails of my site to html version.

Comment: If you are interested, check out this application https://github.com/ramusus/django-email-html

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a lot of people are misreading your question.

To override the import from third party modules, overwriting `sys.modules['django.core.mail']` might work.

It works in simple tests, but it's not thoroughly tested.

```
import sys
from django.core import mail 

def my_send_mail(*args, **kwargs):
    print "Sent!11"

mail.send_mail = my_send_mail
sys.modules['django.core.mail'] = mail


from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('blah')
# output: Sent!11
```

For example, if I put that code in my `settings.py` and launch the `manage.py shell` and import `send_mail`, I get my version.

**My shell session**

```
In [1]: from django.core.mail import send_mail
In [2]: send_mail()
Sent!11
```

**Disclaimer**
I've never done anything like this and don't know if there are any funky ramifications.

Comment: If you are interested, check out this application github.com/ramusus/django-email-html

Answer (score 0):

How about changing `django` a little and substituting original code with your own function? You can actually just add your own function and don't remove the old, as the last definition will be imported. I don't like such solutions, because I don't like patching external libraries (you need to remember about patching them again when you upgrade), but this would solve your problem quickly.

Comment: thanks. that's possible, but I found a little bit cleaner solution, if I can call such solutions like this :-). Without modifying django code

Comment: If you are interested, check out this application https://github.com/ramusus/django-email-html

Comment: How exactly you substitute the old send function? Why now it happens before other modules import it? I'd love to know, to be able to use that trick again.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable. Though it seems a bit risky to depend on the sequence in which modules are loaded. I wonder, if this can be achieved no matter how modules are imported.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.7 added extra attribute `html_message` to `send_mail()` function to send html message.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mail