# Django Forms : Make some text sent by form to email appear bold

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

Quick question. If I have a form that sends to email, is there a way to make some of the sent text show up bold in the email?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.7, [`send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) accepts an `html_message` argument:

> If html_message is provided, the resulting email will be
>   a multipart/alternative email with message as the text/plain content
>   type and html_message as the text/html content type.

Example:

```
send_mail('Subject', 'Content', 'sender@example.com', ['nobody@example.com'], 
          html_message='This is <b>HTML</b> Content')
```

For Django<1.7, you can either use a solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685910/771848), or use a third-party, like [django-email-html](https://github.com/ramusus/django-email-html).

---

Also, there is another third-party package that you should consider using - [django-mail-templated](https://github.com/artemrizhov/django-mail-templated). It basically allows you to describe your email messages in django templates. Additionally, it allows to send html messages defined in `html` block in the template.

For example:

- create a template

  ```
  {% block subject %}
  Email subject
  {% endblock %}

  {% block body %}
  This is a plain text.
  {% endblock %}

  {% block html %}
  This is <b>HTML</b> Content.
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- and send it:

  ```
  from mail_templated import send_mail
  send_mail('my_template.tpl', {}, from_email, [user.email])
  ```

Hope that helps.